# TFS - What happens if I delete a workspace?

Tags: tfs

I started work a lone developer last year and I found VSS is no longer a good option for source control so I decided to use TFS 2010 instead.
I have had to learn everything from a book - of which there are few.
I am currently creating a new build and in my workspaces I see a have 4. I want to delete one of them and rename another.
However I do not know what the consequences of doing this are. If I delete a workspace, will that remove the associated files under source control? How do I check which files these are? What happens if I change a status from active to cloaked?
As you can see, I am a beginner in all this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workspaces are only a mapping from SourceSontrol folders onto your local file system. Also workspace contains information about versions of the files you have locally, so when you hit 'Get Latest Version' only recent changes are sent from server to you, not the whole files. Information on what files are checked out is stored in workspace too, so if you have pending changes in the workspace and delete it then there'll be a bit of a challenge to check these changes in. Renaming of the workspace will not break anything as far as I know.
Article [An introduction to TFS Workspaces](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000333.html) may be interesting to you.

Comment: The only problem deleting a workspace will have is the loss of anything checked out within that workspace. IIRC this is covered in the warning when deleting.

Comment: Currently everything is checked in. However if I delete a workspace, which workspace would  be used for items that previously used that workspace?

Comment: @arame: What do you mean by items? If files and folders then the better view is that the workspace uses files, not vice versa. Files are unaffected by workspaces they are mapped in. One file may be mapped in many workspaces or in no workspace, it doesn't matter. Any workspace that has a mapping for your files will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others have said, the workspace only says what local files you have checked out, and the status, etc.  Workspaces are pretty granulal (i.e. per user and per machine) so you could have mutliple workspaces with the same username in the same project. E.g. if you have a copy of Visual Studio at work and one at home, you could have different files checked out and you wouldn't run into any conflicts like you would have in VSS or something based on VSS Like like VSSConnect.

We've had a couple of people leave out project and have had to go in and remove their workspaces after the fact.  This hasn't been a big deal in terms of any code losses but if you don't have access to the machine anymore you will have to use the TFS tools.

Try TFS Sidekicks, it provides a nice GUI to manage all the nitty-gritty back-end stuff in TFS